# Difference between force.com vs. site.com, etc

Tags: force.com, site.com

What are the key differences among **force.com, data.com, site.com, work.com**, and don't know what else are there in Salesforce?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question has probably received downvote(s) because it doesn't appear that you've done any research prior to asking your question. While some of the information on this topic can be hard to find, other parts should be easy to search for (like the different add-on products to the force.com platform). The things that tend to make good questions here are: 1) Doing your research. 2) Clear explanation of your problem and goal. 3) Being very specific and detailed. 4) Including code (when appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

- **Force.com** is a Platform as a Service (PaaS) product designed to simplify the development and deployment of cloud-based applications and websites. Developers can create apps and websites through the cloud IDE (integrated development environment) and deploy them quickly to Force.com's multi-tenant servers
- **Site.com** is a web content management system (CMS) that makes it easy to build dynamic, data-driven web pages quickly, edit content in real time, and manage your websites.
- **Data.com** is the sales and lead generation component of Salesforce.com's Sales Cloud customer relationship management (CRM) platform. ... The Data.com platform enables sharing of contact data (similar to what is found on business cards) among members through its large user-generated database
- **Work.com** is a corporate performance management platform for sales representatives with a user interface (UI) that resembles a social networking website.
  The platform, which is a Salesforce product, targets employee engagement in three areas: alignment of the team and personal goals with business goals, motivation through public recognition and real-time performance feedback. Employees are encouraged to meet goals through a system that emphasizes recognition and rewards.
- **Database.com** is Salesforce’s primary enterprise database storage. It’s built to store data through the cloud. Database.com is a massive data storage facility where users can securely stash billions of records, retrieve these records for use in developing apps, and create transactions with truly fast response times.
  This cloud-based storage built by Salesforce powers cloud-based applications by providing the data needed to run these applications smoothly. Through advanced database service functions, Database.com is able to guide its users in managing large amounts of organizational data stored inside their secured cloud.

Comment: what else are there in Salesforce ?

Comment: There is one more in this list **Database.com**. I've added it's description in the list above

Comment: Thanks for your post @AladinBanwal - I assume you copied this from somewhere? Can you share the link please?

Comment: Yes, of course, I've copied because as Derek said in a comment above this question is already on the internet. And I've merged this answer from several different sites, you can find by doing the google search.